# Conditionally rendering UI based on cookies and supabase affects the rest of my program Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, supabase, next.js13

I am trying to conditionally render an account button when a user is authenticated; render a login + sign-up button when the user is not authenticated as follows:

My `DesktopBar.tsx` file

```
import { getUser } from "@/app/_actions/userActions.ts"
import { NavItem } from "@/components/NavItem"

export async function DesktopBar() {
  const user = await getUser()
  return (
    <div className="hidden md:flex md:w-full md:justify-between md:p-6">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <NavItem key="home" page="/" text="home" className="text-4xl" />
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center">
        {user ? (
          <NavItem key="/account" page="/account" text="Account" />
        ) : (
          <>
            <NavItem key="/login" page="/login" text="Login" />
            <NavItem key="/sign_up" page="/sign_up" text="Sign Up" />
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My `userActions.ts` file

```
export async function getUser() {
     const { data: user } = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .select("name, is_admin")
        .single()
    return user
    
}
```

When running this code, everything works as expected when refreshing the page. When logged in, it displays Account in my navbar when I am authenticated **before the JS loads** as expected.

The problem arises when I try to use a custom search form component to navigate to a page that is generated via **generateStaticParams**().

My `SearchForm.tsx` file

```
"use client"

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

export function SearchForm() {
  const router = useRouter()

  function onSubmit(data) {
    router.push(`${data[0]}/${data[1]}/${data[2]}`)
  }

  return (
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Button type="submit">Search </Button>
      </form>
  )
}
```

This is a simple abstraction of the form, all you need to know is that it takes in three inputs from a select box, and then routes the user to that route via `router.push()`.

The user is routed to this route: `/[a]/[b]/[c]/page.tsx`

```
import { FC } from "react"

export const revalidate = 20

interface pageProps {
  params: { a: string; b: string; c: string }
}


const page: FC<pageProps> = async ({ params }) => {
  const { a, b, c } = params
    // some logic happens...
}
// generate a combination of pages statically
export function generateStaticParams() {
  const combinations = []

  for (const a of letter1) {
    for (const b of letter2) {
      for (const c of letter3) {
        combinations.push({ a, b, c })
      }
    }
  }
  return combinations
}
export default page
```

When I comment out the **generateStaticParams**() method, everything seems to work. But I have lots of dynamic pages and still want to **statically generate** them at build time rather than navigating to them **dynamically**.

The error message I get is `Dynamic Server usage: cookies`. But I don't expect the code from `Desktopbar.tsx` to affect `/[a]/[b]/[c]/page.tsx`.

Finally, here is my root `layout.tsx` where I render the Desktop bar.

```
import "@/styles/globals.css"
import DesktopBar from "@/components/DesktopBar"


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body className>
          <DesktopBar />
          <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the following from any routes that use the `cookies` function:

```js
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```